# OpenGL Alpha Blending: Why won't the alpha value reduce to 0 after many layers?

Tags: opengl

In my head, if the source alpha value is non-zero and very small, the destination alpha value would have been reduced to 0 if the source is overlayed many times.

Given 8-bit and the blending function:

```cpp
glEnable(GL_BLEND);
glBlendFunc(GL_SRC_ALPHA, GL_ONE_MINUS_SRC_ALPHA);
```

The formula to calculate the new alpha value would be the following if I understood correctly.

[image: formula]

https://www.khronos.org/registry/OpenGL-Refpages/gl2.1/xhtml/glBlendFunc.xml

Testing with the code below indicate this is not the case, what am I missing?

```cpp
// Assume black background
glLineWidth(50);
glBegin(GL_LINES);
    glColor3ub(0xFF, 0xFF, 0xFF);
    glVertex2d(x, y);
    glVertex2d(x + 50, y);
glEnd();
for (int i = 0; i < 500; ++i) {
    glBegin(GL_LINES);
        glColor4ub(0xFF, 0xFF, 0xFF, 1);
        glVertex2d(x, y);
        glVertex2d(x + 50, y);
    glEnd();
}
```

Comment: "*In my head, if the source alpha value is non-zero and very small, the destination alpha value would have been reduced to 0 if the source is overlayed many times.*" Why do you say that? That's not the conclusion the math shows. It suggests that the value would get closer to whatever the destination alpha originally was. Which was... what, exactly?

Comment: I say that because of integer alrithmetic, the term on the left would just be truncated to 0 in every loop. The docs of `glBlendFunc` also says `Despite the apparent precision of the above equations, blending arithmetic is not exactly specified, because blending operates with imprecise integer color values.`

Answer (score 0):

You keep blending a white transparent line with a white solid line. When you blend white with white with the formula

```
destRGBA = scrRGBA * alpha + destRGBA * (1.0 - alpha)
```

the result will be white again and will never change:

```
RGBA(1,1,1,1/255) * 1/255 + RGBA(1,1,1,x) * (1-1/255) = RGBA(1,1,1,x')
```

Comment: Quoting the docs of `glBlendFunc` "Despite the apparent precision of the above equations, blending arithmetic is not exactly specified, because blending operates with imprecise integer color values." I am guessing the alpha value becomes `a_dst = a_src * a_src / 255 + a_dst * (255 - a_src) / 255` in C, everything integer. Then won't `a_src * a_src / 255` be just truncated to 0 every time?

Comment: Would you please point out where does it specify this? The closest thing I can find is "Both normalized integer and floating-point formats will resolve, in the shader, to a vector of floating-point values, whereas integral formats will resolve to a vector of integers." Which says it may be processed in integers. It also does not explain the quote in `glBlendFunc` documentation.

Comment: @Hogcryat See [`glColor`](https://www.khronos.org/registry/OpenGL-Refpages/gl2.1/xhtml/glColor.xml) *"Unsigned integer color components, when specified, are linearly mapped to floating-point values such that the largest representable value maps to 1."*. See also [OpenGL 4.6 API Compatibility Profile Specification](https://www.khronos.org/registry/OpenGL/specs/gl/glspec46.compatibility.pdf)